Horror Movie : People doing the "hands in the air" move
I remember we rented it at the videoclub around the year 2000. We used to do that a lot at the time so I'm nearly sure it is from this period of time.
The movie was a about a demonic entity who could "possess" people and when the people were possessed, they did the "raising the roof" dance move.
I remember a scene when the main character entered a church and all the people there were possessed and began to do the "dance" and looking at him/her and that felt kind of strange/funny. The church scene happens at night and I think it rained too.
The information I'm about to give may be completely false but I think the main chararacter is a woman journalist or writer and she had a friend who was close to her and she finally comes to know that he was part of that demonic group of people... It seemed like they had people everywhere that's why the church was full of them (a bit like in The Invaders).
The movie takes place in a big city of the US (like New York or similar). The main character lived in an appartement if I remember well.
This is all I remember from the movie.

Do you mean the 'raising the roof' gesture?

@Walt LOL yes that is it exactly :D

Good to know. ;) The thing is, parishioners raising their hands as they're possessed by a spirit is a bit common (in films and real life). So no other details about that entity spring to mind? About the protagonists or their nature (were they investigators, maybe?)

@Walt The information I'm about to give may be completely false but I think the main char. is a woman journalist or writer and she had a friend who was close to her and she finally comes to know that he was part of that demonic group of people... It seemed like they had people everywhere that's why the church was full of them (a bit like in The Invaders

@Walt I think I've found it ! But I have to be sure people to the dance move now. Pretty sure this is it though, I "recognize" some scenes (the one in the church and the one in the friend's office for example)

Heh, what I had in mind too. :) [Though I wasn't entirely sure, sorry. And I didn't remember if it had that gesture there either.] You can always answer your own question, if you want.

@Walt You helped me answer it so the bounty can go your way, no problem :)

OK, I'll put it up.

A lot of it made me think of Lost Souls from 2000 with Winona Ryder and Ben Chaplin, one of several thrillers around the Millennium dealing with the Antichrist (like End of Days and Bless the Child).

A small group of Catholics led by an ailing priest believe that Satan intends to become man, just as God did in the person of Jesus. The writings of a possessed mental patient lead them to Peter Kelson, a writer who studies serial killers. They think it's his body Satan will occupy. The youngest in the group, a teacher named Maya Larkin, goes to Peter to investigate further and to convince him to believe in the possibility of Evil incarnate. Other signs come to him as he and Maya them take a journey full of strange occurrences, self-discovery, and an ultimate showdown. 

And near the end:

Peter and [Maya] go to his uncle's congregation and it is filled with Peter's family, friends and people that he and [Maya] have been seeing in dreams. Turns out that this is not a catholic ceremony but instead a satanic ceremony, kind of a coming out party for the antichrist.

So I don't really remember the exact hand gestures there, but the rest seems to fit and several people are possessed during the film.




Thank you again. I'll watch the movie again, maybe that whole dance thing was just my imagination as a kid I do not know, though I was pretty sure.

I've since located the church scene near the end.  They're not raising the roof.

Indeed, I watched it again and there was no such thing. I think I've mixed two movies up.
